# Copy file with scp command

Tags: ssh, scp

Trying to copy a file from RPi to my PC:

```
$ scp MyFile.pdf user@192.168.0.83:~ 

ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.83 port 22: connection refused

lost connection
```

When copying the same file from my PC it works fine:

```
$ scp pi@192.168.0.82:/home/pi/Downloads/MagPi46.pdf /home/user/Desktop/
pi@192.168.0.82's password: 
MagPi46.pdf                              100%   21MB   1.0MB/s   00:21
```

Is there a reason to why the file can be copied from PC to PC and not from RPi to PC ?

Comment: Is your Pi running an SSH server?

Comment: don't know, how to find out ?

Comment: I think Pi is running SSH server cause I can connect to it with ssh command

Comment: Is your PC running SSH server, when you want to connect to it?

Comment: Yes, I am connected to RPi with SSH while trying to copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Pi is running an ssh server. Your PC is not. Both have ssh clients available. There are numerous ssh server packages available, but I don't know what kind of machine you are running on to recommend one. A simple Google "install ssh server 'machine type, i.e., Linux'" should suffice.

To test that it works on the machine you install it on, you can usually `ssh user@localhost` and not see that error message.

If you do have one installed, make sure that the port (22) is actually open on your firewall.

Comment: installed ssh server -> http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-1204/